# How to calculate area of segments in a circle generated by random 3 lines connecting 3 sets of 2 points along the circumference in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, geometry, area, segment

I need to calculate the area of segments in a circle generated by 3 random lines inside the circle ( Each line touching circumference of the circle).

Below is the code I used to plot the circle and random 3 lines. Need to calculate the area of each segment generated.

```
clear all
close all
clc

x = 6;
y = 7;
r = 3;

th = 0:pi/50:2*pi;
xunit = r * cos(th) + x;
yunit = r * sin(th) + y;
h = plot(xunit, yunit);
hold on
axis equal


p1 = randi([1 length(xunit)]);
p2 = randi([1 length(xunit)]);

p3 = randi([1 length(xunit)]);
p4 = randi([1 length(xunit)]);

p5 = randi([1 length(xunit)]);
p6 = randi([1 length(xunit)]);



%% Get the intersection points


[xi_1,yi_1] = polyxpoly([xunit(p1) xunit(p2)] , [yunit(p1) yunit(p2)] , [xunit(p3) xunit(p4)] , [yunit(p3) yunit(p4)]);
[xi_2,yi_2] = polyxpoly([xunit(p1) xunit(p2)] , [yunit(p1) yunit(p2)] , [xunit(p5) xunit(p6)] , [yunit(p5) yunit(p6)]);
[xi_3,yi_3] = polyxpoly([xunit(p3) xunit(p4)] , [yunit(p3) yunit(p4)] , [xunit(p5) xunit(p6)] , [yunit(p5) yunit(p6)]);



%% Plot the cuts and the intersections

% Plot the cuts

plot([xunit(p1) xunit(p2)],[yunit(p1) yunit(p2)]);
hold on
plot([xunit(p3) xunit(p4)],[yunit(p3) yunit(p4)]);
hold on
plot([xunit(p5) xunit(p6)],[yunit(p5) yunit(p6)]);
hold on

% Plot intersection points

plot(xi_1,yi_1,'ro');
hold on
plot(xi_2,yi_2,'ro');
hold on
plot(xi_3,yi_3,'ro');
hold off
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The way you are describing your issue isn't understandable. A segment [AB] is the set of points $M$ that are between $A$ and $B$ on line $AB$. Therefore it has no area. Maybe you want to speak about the area of the triangle defined by 3 random lines

Comment: And how do you define the triangle defined by the three lines?